# Prolog find non related graph nodes

Tags: prolog, graph-theory, transitive-closure

I have the following graph:

[image: GRAPH]

My goal is to get all the direct connections of a certain node and all of the nodes that are not connected with a certain node for example:

**connections(1,X).**

X=3;

X=4;

X=5;

X=6.

**noConnections(1,X).**

X=2.

**This is my code:**

```
% knowledge base

path(1, 6).
path(1, 5).
path(1, 4).
path(1, 3).
path(6, 5).
path(5, 4).
path(4, 2).
path(2, 3).

% rules

connections(X,Y) :- path(X,Y) ; path(Y,X).
noConnections(X,Y) :- \+path(X,Y).
```

As you can see I succesfully did **connections** but cant find out how to do it for **noConnections**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way :

```
connected(X, Y) :-
    path(X,Y);path(Y,X).

% fetching all nodes of the database
collectAllNodesButX(X, L) :-
    setof(A, B^(path(A,B);path(B,A)), L1),
    select(X, L1, L).

% main predicate
notConnected(X, L) :-
   collectAllNodesButX(X,Nodes),
   % we exclude all nodes that succeed the predicate connected/2
   findall(Y, (member(Y, Nodes), \+connected(X, Y)), L).
```

Now, we get :

```
?- notConnected(1, L).
L = [2] .

?- notConnected(X, [2]).
X = 1 .
```

Comment: Yes, There is a typo it is collectAllNodesButX(X,L). I correct my code, sorry !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `not(Goal)` predicate. You can say `not(path(X,Y)); not(path(Y,X)).` which is just the inversion of your goals. If the node directly connects to whichever node you are checking for, the result is false. No connections returns true then.